# How does thermodynamical entropy change when I let a gas flow out of a box?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Suppose that I have a box which contains a gas. Let the total thermodynamical entropy inside the box be $S_1$. Now suppose that the gas flows out of the box and all that is left is a vacuum. Then the final entropy inside the box is $0$. Therefore, the difference in entropy inside the box is $\Delta S=-S_1$.

However, thermodynamical entropy is defined up to an additive constant. Therefore, we could also have defined the initial entropy as some different value $S_2$. Now the difference between final and initial entropy is $\Delta S=-S_2$.

However, shouldn't differences in entropy be independent of the additive constant that we choose?

Comment: if you choose that vacuum (vacuum of what?) has entropy = 0, you're setting the constant. If you use another constant, as you do in $S_2$, the vacuum has no zero entropy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you called $S_1$ is really:

$$S_1 = S_1 (U,V,n) + K_1 $$

Where $K_1$ is the additive constant. The variation would be:

$$\Delta S = S_1(U_f,V_f,n_f)+K_1-S_1(U_i,V_i,n_i)-K_1=S_1(U_f,V_f,n_f)-S_1(U_i,V_i,n_i) $$

And if the first term on the right hand side is $0$, then $\Delta S=-S_1(U_i,V_i,n_i)$ which as you can see is independent of the additive constant $K_1$. Furthermore, if what you called $S_2$ is simply $S_2=S_1(U,V,n)+K_2$, so that it only differs from $S_1$ by an additive constant, its variation is also independent of $K_2$ by the reasoning above.

Of course if $S_2=S_2(U,V,n)+K_2$, you just have a different entropy function.